# Python not recognising List Object

Tags: python, list, hadoop, mapreduce, bigdata

I am currently writing some Data Processing code in Python for a Hadoop tutorial and running into some issues I don't quite understand. Here is the code:

```
from mrjob.job import MRJob

class tutorial4(MRJob):

    def mapper(self, _, line):
        fields = line.split(',')
        stockTotal = int(float(fields[6]) * float(fields[7]))
        key = fields[1]
        date = fields[2]
        pair = (key, date, stockTotal)
        yield(None, pair)

    def reducer(self, _, pair):
        pair = list(pair)
        sortedValues = sorted(pair, reverse = True, key = pair[2])
        yield(None, pair)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    tutorial4.run()
```

The problem I am having here is the yield keyword in the Mapper Object is returning a generator object. I need a list in the Reducer Object so I am trying to turn the Pair list fromt the Mapper into a list by doing:

```
pair = list(pair)
```

When I do this and try running it Python returns a "List Object is not callable" error. Now I've looked at a few other answers on here and other places and the standard answer seems to be that I am using lists somewhere else in the code and not the inbuilt List object from Python itself but I'm not doing that here and cant figure out whats wrong. Can someone help me out here?

Comment: Have you created a variable called `list` to hold a list object? If such a variable is in scope it would shadow the `list()` type constructor.

Comment: No, not using or created a variable anywhere with the list name

Comment: Are you entirely sure? What does `print(list)` do if you put it right above `pair = list(pair)`?

Comment: it returns <class 'list'>

Comment: And `pair = list(pair)` still gives that error about List Object not being callable? That wasn't the result of a one-off issue, e.g. in an interactive terminal? The error references the line you're showing us in your question?

Comment: Yup, tried it on multiple different terminals and restarted a couple times too. Error takes place on Line 16 is what Python returns.

Comment: Can you run this with a debugger? Something weird appears to be going on.